# Read/Write value for some time,pyserial throws ClearCommError failed (PermissionError(13, 'Access denied', None, 5)

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

I've created a desktop UI by PySide2, then communicate to USB device by pyserial, but read/write data for some time, i got the error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\t\Desktop\test\tabWidget.py", line 160, in timeTick
        bTemp.append(float(setCommand(self.mainwindow.ser, 'drum_temp')))
    File "C:\Users\t\Desktop\test\utils.py", line 88, in setCommand
        while serialObj.inWaiting() > 0:
    File "C:\Users\t\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 590, in inWaiting
        return self.in_waiting
    File "C:\Users\t\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 257, in in_waiting
        raise SerialException("ClearCommError failed ({!r})".format(ctypes.WinError()))
    serial.serialutil.SerialException: ClearCommError failed (PermissionError(13, 'Access denied', None, 5)
```

First of all, i open the serial port when click the 'connect' button, then read/write data to device by one function. Sometimes throws the error when initialize some commands to device, or write command to read data from device.

Something weird is my laptop run the code is fine, but another laptop from my colleague always throws this error. And use the administrator to run code on command line, same result.

This is the environment:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- python 3.6.8 -> conda create -n py36 python=3.6
- PySide2 5.13.0
- pyserial 3.4
- pip 19.1.1

And the read/write function as follow:

```
def setCommand(serialObj, command):
    try:
        if serialObj is not None and serialObj.isOpen():
            serialObj.flushInput()
            byteData = bytes()
            if len(command) > 0:
                serialObj.write(command.encode() + '\r'.encode())
                time.sleep(0.1)
                while serialObj.inWaiting() > 0:
                    byteData += serialObj.read(serialObj.inWaiting()) 
        return byteData.decode('ascii').rstrip('\r\n')
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        pass
    return None
```

This is serial setting

```
serialObj = serial.Serial(
    port='COM3',
    baudrate=57600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=0.5,
    writeTimeout=0)
```

I expect the code will run on any laptop, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see happens when the device on the other side of the connection resets or closes the connection for any other reason.

Are you using the same USB adaptor on both laptops? If so, maybe try using any other USB port to connect it to. This might be a hardware issue one of the USB controllers. It might also be another device connected to the same USB host interfering or a strange driver issue.

There are many hardware and software tools you can use to check your USB ports. See, for instance, [here](https://www.usb.org/usb2tools) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/microsoft-usb-test-tool--mutt--devices).

Comment: The laptops aren't using same USB adaptor, just connect individually at different time to run my desktop program

Comment: You mean they ARE using the same USB adaptor, right? There is something closing the connection abruptly, and that's why you see that error.

Comment: No, the device connect to my laptop by USB, and the OS is Win10 64bit Home edition, and run the code is stable, and the laptop is ASUS. The other laptops are Microsoft Surface or Mac book air, all win10 64bit pro edition, but all run the code and same error.

Comment: And all software versions and drivers are the same? Have you tried switching to other USB ports or adding a USB hub with power supply in between? Sometimes USB devices require more power than what the computer is able to supply, that leads to device resets and all... You can try removing the USB while you're running your program to verify if you see the same error.

Comment: After upgrading the USB drvier, the problem seem to be resolved. Thanks